# JAXB unmarshal elements of XML to Map

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an XML file. In this file, some of the elements are have attributes that change. I want to put those attributes into a Map. How do I do this?

My XML is:

```
<ROW id='1'>
    <MOBILE>9831138683</MOBILE>
    <VARS>
        <CAUSE>Delayed payment</CAUSE>
        <DO>100.56</DO>
        <LOT>1</LOT>
    </VARS>
</ROW>
<ROW id='2'>
    <MOBILE>9831138684</MOBILE>
    <VARS>
        <NAME>hi</NAME>
        <ADDRESS>Here</ADDRESS>
        <LOT>2</LOT>
    </VARS>
</ROW>
```

In this, the `VARS` element can have attributes which changes and I do not know beforehand what these elements will be.

I have created a class for this purpose:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "ROW")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class SMSDetail {
    @XmlAttribute
    private int id;
    @XmlElement(name = "MOBILE")
    private int mobileNo;
    @XmlElement(name = "VARS")
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(MapAdapter.class)
    private HashMap<String, String> variableMap;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public int getMobileNo() {
        return mobileNo;
    }

    public HashMap<String, String> getVariableMap() {
        return variableMap;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public void setMobileNo(int mobileNo) {
        this.mobileNo = mobileNo;
    }

    public void setVariableMap(HashMap<String, String> variableMap) {
        this.variableMap = variableMap;
    }
}
```

I want to map the `VARS` element to a `Map`. I want the tags such as `CAUSE`, `LOT` to be keys and their values to be the values in the map. I have written an `XmlAdapater` for this purpose:

```
public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapElements[], Map<String, String>> {
    public MapAdapter() {
    }

    @Override
    public MapElements[] marshal(Map<String, String> arg0) throws Exception {
        MapElements[] mapElements = new MapElements[arg0.size()];
        int i = 0;
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : arg0.entrySet())
            mapElements[i++] = new MapElements(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());

        return mapElements;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(MapElements[] arg0) throws Exception {
        Map<String, String> r = new TreeMap<String, String>();
        for (MapElements mapelement : arg0)
            r.put(mapelement.key, mapelement.value);
        return r;
    }
}

class MapElements {
    @XmlAttribute
    public String key;
    @XmlAttribute
    public String value;

    private MapElements() {
    } //Required by JAXB

    public MapElements(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

This adapter is giving me `null` for the `variableMap` variable. How should the Adapter be modified for this?

Comment: do you want your tag name (e.g cause,do,lot) to be your key in map?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You could do the following:

### XmlAdapter (`MapAdapter`)

You could do the following for your `XmlAdapter` where you convert an instance of `Map` to an object that has a `List` of DOM `Element`.  You will construct the instances of `Element` so that the name is they key from the map entry, and the text content is the value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAnyElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class MapAdapter extends XmlAdapter<MapAdapter.AdaptedMap, Map<String, String>> {

    private DocumentBuilder documentBuilder;

    public MapAdapter() throws Exception {
        documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
    }

    public static class AdaptedMap {        
        @XmlAnyElement
        public List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<Element>();
    }

    @Override
    public AdaptedMap marshal(Map<String, String> map) throws Exception {
        Document document = documentBuilder.newDocument();
        AdaptedMap adaptedMap = new AdaptedMap();
        for(Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            Element element = document.createElement(entry.getKey());
            element.setTextContent(entry.getValue());
            adaptedMap.elements.add(element);
        }
        return adaptedMap;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> unmarshal(AdaptedMap adaptedMap) throws Exception {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        for(Element element : adaptedMap.elements) {
            map.put(element.getLocalName(), element.getTextContent());
        }
        return map;
    }


}
```

### Optimizing the Use of `MapAdapter`

To improve performance we want to minimize the number of times the `DocumentBuiderFactory` and `DocumentBuilder` is instantiated.  We can do this by creating an instance of the `MapAdapter` for JAXB to use and set it on the `Marshaller` and `Unmarshaller`.  This way JAXB will use that instance instead of creating a new one each time the adapter is required.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.*;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(SMSDetail.class);

        MapAdapter mapAdapter = new MapAdapter();

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setAdapter(mapAdapter);
        File xml = new File("src/forum27182975/input.xml");
        SMSDetail smsDetail = (SMSDetail) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);

        Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
        marshaller.setAdapter(mapAdapter);
        marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
        marshaller.marshal(smsDetail, System.out);
    }

}
```

---

### If You are Using MOXy as your JAXB (JSR-222) Provider

If you are using MOXy as your JAXB provider then you can leverage the `@XmlVariableNode` extension to make the mapping of this use case easier:

- http://blog.bdoughan.com/2013/06/moxys-xmlvariablenode-using-maps-key-as.html

Comment: Which confirms with your article. http://java.dzone.com/articles/jaxb-and-javautilmap :) nice one.